# Use dplyr to create a new variable using mutate, whereby the new value gets applied for every relevant value of a third variable

Tags: r, dplyr

I have data which looks like this

```
df <- data.frame(
ID = c(rep("A12345",5), rep("A23456",10), rep("A34567",5), "A45678", "A67891", rep("A78910",8), "A91011", 
       rep("A10111",4), rep("A11121",3), "A12131", "A16731"),
indicator = c(rep("colchicine",5), rep("febuxosat",9), "hosps", rep("colchicine",5), "hosps", "colchicine", 
              rep("allopurinol",8), "allopurinol", 
              rep("colchicine",3), "hosps", rep("colchicine",3), "colchicine", "allopurinol"),
Date = c("2004-12-08", "2005-01-28", "2005-07-15", "2005-08-23", "2005-11-30", "2007-02-01", "2007-07-20", "2014-06-03", 
         "2008-04-17",
         "2008-12-19", "2009-09-09", "2010-02-24", "2010-11-01", "2010-12-03", "2011-08-10", "2012-11-05", "2012-12-17", 
         "2012-12-19", "2013-10-03", "2013-12-11", "2014-03-26", "2015-11-12", "2014-08-07", "2008-01-31", "2008-02-21", 
         "2008-09-19", "2008-11-06", "2009-01-06", "2009-01-14", "2009-03-25", "2009-03-27", "2009-06-18", "2009-08-18", 
         "2009-09-08", "2009-11-13", "2010-01-21", "2010-04-19", "2010-07-07", "2010-08-06", "2010-08-19")
)
```

What I want to do, is if, for the ID variable, there is ANY instance where indicator == "hosps", then create a new indicator called "hosp_ever", which is equal to 1. If, for any ID, there was never an instance of "hosps" in the indicator variable, then the new "hosp_ever" variable is equal to 0.

This is how I have tried to do this:

```
df_group <- df %>%
group_by(ID) %>%
mutate(hosp_ever = ifelse(indicator == "hosps", "Y", "N"))
```

This creates the new hosp_ever variable, but only assigns a "Y" for instances where indicator == hosps, hosp_ever is not correctly assigned to IDs where the indicator != hosps, but they have had a hosps event at some date.

This is what I would like my output to look like

```
df_group <- df %>%
mutate(hosps_ever = c(rep("N",5), rep("Y",9), "Y", rep("N",5), "Y", "N", 
     rep("N",8), "N", 
     rep("Y",3), "Y", rep("N",3), "N", "N"))
```

Does anyone know where I'm going wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `any`to check for at least one of the `indicator` in a certain `ID` group equals to `hosps`

```r
library(dplyr)

df_group <- df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(hosp_ever = ifelse(any(indicator == "hosps"), "Y", "N"))

df_group
#> # A tibble: 40 x 4
#> # Groups:   ID [11]
#>    ID     indicator  Date       hosp_ever
#>    <fct>  <fct>      <fct>      <chr>    
#>  1 A12345 colchicine 2004-12-08 N        
#>  2 A12345 colchicine 2005-01-28 N        
#>  3 A12345 colchicine 2005-07-15 N        
#>  4 A12345 colchicine 2005-08-23 N        
#>  5 A12345 colchicine 2005-11-30 N        
#>  6 A23456 febuxosat  2007-02-01 Y        
#>  7 A23456 febuxosat  2007-07-20 Y        
#>  8 A23456 febuxosat  2014-06-03 Y        
#>  9 A23456 febuxosat  2008-04-17 Y        
#> 10 A23456 febuxosat  2008-12-19 Y        
#> # ... with 30 more rows
```

Created on 2018-06-26 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0.9000).